# Tem algum comando HTML que deixa de um jeito no celular e de outro no computador? E também tem algum código universal para o tamanho dos elementos?

Tags: html, css

Estou criando uma página HTML para alguém especial, creio que está pessoa vai abrir a página no celular, porém, minha página aparece de dois modos diferentes no computador e no celular. No computador ela aparece toda bonitinha, agora no celular um dos elementos vai para o topo sendo que eu quero ele centralizado na tela. Por isso estava pensando se existe algum código que altera a página apenas no celular, pra utilizar o comando `top: px`.

Também queria saber se tem algum comando "universal" pra colocar no tamanho do elemento, pois eu coloquei os pixels de acordo com o meu monitor, no monitor de um amigo meu fica uma parte sobrando da página.
Obs: já estou usando meta para celular, o meu problema é mais com a posição do elemento e não a adaptabilidade mobile.

Meu código tá assim:

**Parte do CSS**

```
//carousel com bootstrap//
#myCarousel
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

//imagem que ocupa a tela//
#Random
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 626px;
  max-width: 833px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Obs 2.0: aparentemente o comando `vertical-align: middle` não está funcionando, pois a imagem não foi centralizada no verticalmente no celular.

*Edit:*

[image: Imagem da página pelo computador]

[image: Imagem da página pelo celular]

Como podem ver a página está responsiva, o meu problema é que no celular o elemento fica lá no topo, eu quero centralizar ele pra deixar com uma estética melhor.

Comment: Cara no Youtube existem centenas de cursos de graça, em português de como fazer sites responsivos e tudo mais, recomendo fortemente que vc pesquise por algum e estude bastante. Abs

Comment: Criar sites responsivos dar muito trabalho mesmo. Você vai ter que `Dominar` `HTML`, `CSS` e `Java Script`. Não existe uma fórmula fixa para se criar sites responsivos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá Eduardo beleza? você pode arrumar isso utulizando flexbox, segue o código..

```
#myCarousel {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;

 display:flex;
 // O justify-content alinha o item no centro horizontalmente
 justify-content:center;
 // O align-content alinha o item no centro verticalmente
 align-content:center;
}

#myCarousel img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 626px;
 max-width: 833px;
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
}
```

E respondendo sua pergunta, sim, para definir estilos diferentes em dispositivos diferentes utilizamos as medias querys, o exemplo do código abaixo faz o seguinte: Altera o background do #myCarousel para 'red' somente se a tela do dispositivo ter no máximo 763px, ou seja, no celular..

```
@media screen and(max-width:763px){
 #myCarousel {
  background: red;
 }
}
```

O código abaixo faz o seguinte: Altera o background do #myCarousel para 'green' somente se a tela do dispositivo ter no mínimo 764px, ou seja, no tablet ou desktop..

```
@media screen and(min-width:764px){
 #myCarousel {
  background: green;
 }
}
```

Veja o código no [codepen](https://codepen.io/mdsweb/pen/GRZoMaX)

Answer (score -2):

Não entendi muito bem, mas experimenta adicionar em cada página HTML:

```
<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1″>
```

CSS

```
@viewport {
  width: device-width ;
  zoom: 1.0 ;
}
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tumhac